# Is there a more concise jQuery syntax to disable a submit button on form submit?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code to disable a submit button when the form is submitted:

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
});
```

Is there a more concise syntax for this?

Comment: Why what's wrong with what you have? It is concise enough.

Comment: I was hoping for a `disabled()` function of some kind.

Comment: No, there isn't such a function, but `$('input[type=submit]', this).prop('disabled', true);` is clear enough I think. :)

Comment: Why `prop()` instead of `attr()`?

Comment: I explained it shortly in my answer. If you still don't understand it, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jQuery disable plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/disable).

```
$('input').disable(); //disables
$('input').enable(); //enables
$('input').toggleDisabled(); //toggles
$('input').toggleEnabled(); //toggles
$('input').toggleDisabled(true); //disables
$('input').toggleEnabled(true); //enables
```

Or, if you don't want a plugin, you can use this:

```
jQuery.fn.disable = function() {
    $( this ).prop( "disabled", true );
};

$('input[type=submit]', this).disable();
```

Comment: A plugin for this trivial task? Common. :)

Comment: You should use `.prop()` for setting the `disabled` attribute on jQuery > 1.6, not `.attr()`.

Comment: Your non-plugin solution is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: @Shef: Why do you say "should"? Both `prop` and `attr` work equally well.

Comment: @arezzo I am not the one who says so, the docs do. Just because something works now, doesn't mean it won't be deprecated in the future.

Comment: So the docs say say that `attr` shouldn't be used any more? What about all of the code out there that's using `attr`? Is it going to stop working?

Comment: @arezzo Hmm... you seem to wanna take it the way you like to. I am telling you the docs suggest/advice to use `.prop()` not `.attr()` for setting the `disabled` and `checked` states.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'd give it an ID, first of all, otherwise you'll disable *every* submit button, which may or may not be what you intend.

Other than that, [that's about it](http://docs.jquery.com/Frequently_Asked_Questions#How_do_I_disable.2Fenable_a_form_element.3F) unless you want to use the [disable plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/disable).

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#myform').submit(function(){
    $('input[type=submit]', this).prop('disabled', true);
});
```

It can't get more concise than this. It is clean enough. I changed `$.attr()` with [`$.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), because this is what you should use to set and get values, which change the state of an element, but not the attribute itself.

From the docs:

> The `.prop()` method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the `.attr()` method.

Comment: Ok. I just read the docs you linked to. How do you know if you're dealing with a property or an attribute. None of the examples mentioned on the docs include `disabled`. Are you sure it's not an `attribute`?

Comment: @arezzo [Yes, they do](http://api.jquery.com/prop/#prop2). I am quoting you from the docs. It's easy to hit CTRL+S to find where the text was quoted from.

Answer (score 0):

One cleaner version can be this:

```
$(this).find(':submit').attr('disabled', true);
```

also

```
$(this).find(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
```